# Reducing redundancy of es6 modules import statement

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I've started using es6 for a project, and quickly discovered that using import as such:

```
import {Account} from 'controllers/account'
import {Activity} from 'controllers/activity'
import {BillingEdit} from 'controllers/billing-edit'
import {BillingSummary} from 'controllers/billing-summary'
import {Billing} from 'controllers/billing'
import {BillingPlan} from 'controllers/billing-plan'
import {Components} from 'controllers/components'
import {Dashboard} from 'controllers/dashboard'
import {Devices} from 'controllers/devices'
import {Feedback} from 'controllers/feedback'
import {Frame} from 'controllers/frame'
import {Help} from 'controllers/help'
import {Login} from 'controllers/login'
import {Membership} from 'controllers/membership'
import {Navigation} from 'controllers/navigation'
import {Notifications} from 'controllers/notifications'
import {Password} from 'controllers/password'
import {Perks} from 'controllers/perks'
import {PlanIssues} from 'controllers/plan-issues'
import {PlanClaims} from 'controllers/plan.claims'
import {PlanContract} from 'controllers/plan.contract'
import {PlanDetails} from 'controllers/plan.details'
import {PlanDevices} from 'controllers/plan.devices'
import {Plan} from 'controllers/plan'
import {PlanTerms} from 'controllers/plan.terms'
import {PlanItems} from 'controllers/plan.items'
import {Plans} from 'controllers/plans'
import {Profile} from 'controllers/profile'
```

Is leading to redundancy, and will become difficult to maintain.

I can of course generate this dynamically by making a task that recurses through the directory, but I'm wondering if es6 has a solution to this problem

Comment: What exactly is redundant? Are you planning to import many of those modules somewhere else as well? You could simply create a single module that imports and exports all of them and then import that module instead. E.g. `import {foo, bar, baz} from 'controllers'`

Comment: My main concern is maintainability, I have over two hundred of these declarations now. Would it be possible to import them all into one, export them, and then import all of them into another file with `import {*} from 'controllers'`, or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes. `import * as controllers from 'controllers'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy including all controllers, then you could add a `index.js` in your `controllers` folder. In it you would do what you did here and include everything, then you would re-export it all as members of one object.

**controllers/index.js**

```
import {Account} from './account'
import {Activity} from './activity'
import {BillingEdit} from './billing-edit'
import {BillingSummary} from './billing-summary'

const controllers = {
  Account,
  Activity,
  BillingEdit,
  BillingSummary
}

export default controllers
```

**app.js**

```
import Controllers from './controllers'

// now you can access controllers like this
console.log(Controllers.Account)
console.log(Controllers.BillingSummary)
```

or you could import only the ones you need like so

**app_alt.js**

```
import { Account, Activity } from './controllers'

console.log(Account)
console.log(Activity)
```

or you can mix and match the approaches

**app_mix.js**

```
import Controllers, { Account, Activity } from './controllers'

console.log(Controllers.Account)
console.log(Account)
console.log(Controllers.BillingSummary)
```